# Get parent-child relationship between tables through application

Tags: java, database, oracle

I have a `java` application which uses `Carbanado`to interact with Oracle Database.

I want to know the dependency graph (where dependency is a foreign-key constraint) of all the tables to do further processing through the application.

As an example:

```
Table A defines dependency over Table B and Table C (means Table A has foreign key constraint on Table B and Table C).
Table B defines dependency over Table C and Table D.
```

I want something like this (it will be a 2-D graph in real scenario).

```
Table A=>Table B=>Table C=>Table D
```

This given an idea that rows in Table D are to be deleted first before deleting corresponding rows in Table A, B and C.

All the entity classes implement a common interface (`Storable`) and dependencies are annotated with `@Join`. Loading all the classes and using extensive reflection seems like one way to do this.

```
>>Load all classes.
>>Create 2D matrix (adjacency matrix) and populate it by going through each class and extracting/processing @Join annotation.
>>Put 0/1 at suitable position.
>>Final matrix will be showing the dependencies.
>>Perform any topological operation.
```

Is there any better way?

**PS:**

*Additional Info*:

1. Just to give you an idea, further processing will create an snapshot of data (in XML/JSON) format as per the dependency.
2. Dependency graph is required to delete the records in proper order.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not *exactly* what you are looking for, but you can query [`ALL_CONSTRAINTS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1037.htm#i1576022) (or `USER_CONSTRAINTS`) and [`ALL_CONS_COLUMNS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1035.htm) to build the adjacency list of the dependency graph.

As an example, something *like* that will return the *from* and *to* table for foreign key constraints:

```
SELECT uc.OWNER, uc.CONSTRAINT_NAME, 
       uc.TABLE_NAME from_table, 
       acc.TABLE_NAME to_table
  FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS uc LEFT JOIN ALL_CONS_COLUMNS acc
  ON uc.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME = acc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
     AND uc.OWNER = acc.OWNER
  WHERE uc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R';
```

---

Given that schema:

```
CREATE TABLE A(N NUMBER(2), PRIMARY KEY (N));
CREATE TABLE B(N NUMBER(2) REFERENCES A(N));
CREATE TABLE C(N NUMBER(2) REFERENCES A(N), M NUMBER(2) REFERENCES A(N));
```

It will produce:

```
OWNER   CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM_TABLE  TO_TABLE
SYLVAIN SYS_C008530     C           A
SYLVAIN SYS_C008529     C           A
SYLVAIN SYS_C008528     B           A
```

Comment: I don't see foreign key constraints being displayed. All I see is system tables in FROM and TO table. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It doesn't seem to return User constraints and only returns WRM$_SNAPSHOT and WRM$_DATABASE_INSTANCE in TABLE_NAME and R_TABLE_NAME.